# How to Stop Docker Containers from Jenkinsfile

Tags: docker, jenkins

Before I run my Jenkinsfile I want to delete/stop all the containers are running in my EC2 instance (my jenkinsfile attached),  how to do that???

```
node {
    def app
    stage('Clone repository') {
        /* Cloning the Repository to our Workspace */
        checkout scm
    }

    stage('Build image') {
        /* This builds the actual image */
        app = docker.build("mendel/nodeapp7")
    }

    stage('run image') {
        /* This builds the actual image */
        app.run("--name pngimage_build_${env.BUILD_NUMBER} -i -t -p 80:80")
    }

    stage('Test image') {     
        app.inside {
            echo "Tests passed"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems you are pretty new here, so I would like to point out a potential problem with your question that makes it less likely to get a response. Within the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Help Center document, there is a recommendation to **Write a title that summarizes the specific problem**. The current title (_"Hey. everyone, I've got a question about Jenkinsfile"_) does not clearly & concisely communicate the problem. I would recommend something like _"How to Stop Docker Containers from Jenkinsfile"_.

Comment: @Men are you trying to stop other builds of the same job or all other containers on the docker host?  If all other containers on the host, do you have exclusive access to the host, or to put it another way, how would you know you're not disrupting other builds?